# Getting an error Where Valueerror Needs to be more than 1

Tags: python

When enter this below

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

I get this error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python-files\ex13.py", line 3, in <module>
    script, first, second, third = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>>
```

Comment: How are you calling your script? What you've written is fine, but only if your calling your script like so `python script.py a b c`

Comment: I am looking at the book and it doesn't show me how to call it. I am using notepad +++ to run the script

Comment: Appreciate your help. I see what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access command line arguments, these arguments are sent only when you call the script this way:

```
python script.py first_argument second_argument third_argument
```

Every argument is separated by a space. The error you are getting is because you are trying to access to the arguments but you are not passing them.

Try calling the script passing three arguments and it will get fixed